# Objective c - Cell Reuse, AutoLayout and Dynamic Cell Height, How to re-use cells when adding Youtube in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a UITableView that holds information such as an Image, User, Date, Message and a Youtube Video (if there is a Youtube Video). I have used Auto Layout throughout the App and this all worked until i wanted to add Youtube Videos with a UIWebView.

Whats happening is that i don't think i have got the code right for re-using the cells in my UITableView so when i scroll, the cells just don't scroll properly as if the data has been jumbled up.

Just wanted to ask where i am going wrong, i will show you the code:

Custom Cell that has Dynamic Height:

```
#import "PostTableViewCell.h"

        @implementation PostTableViewCell

        @synthesize main;
        @synthesize top;
        @synthesize center;
        @synthesize centerLeft;
        @synthesize centerRight;
        @synthesize bottom;
        @synthesize labelMessage;
        @synthesize labelCat;
        @synthesize labelSubCat;
        @synthesize labelCountry;
        @synthesize labelUser;
        @synthesize labelDate;
        @synthesize imageviewThreadImage;
        @synthesize youtube;
        @synthesize webviewYoutube;
        @synthesize labelYoutubeTitle;

        - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
            self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
            if (self) {
            [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

            CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
            //CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

            main = [UIView new];
            [self.contentView addSubview:main];
            main.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [main sizeToFit];
            main.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            top = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:top];
            top.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [top sizeToFit];
            top.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            labelUser = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelUser];
            labelUser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelUser sizeToFit];
            [labelUser setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelUser.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelDate = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelDate];
            labelDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelDate sizeToFit];
            [labelDate setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelDate.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            center = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:center];
            center.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [center sizeToFit];
            center.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            imageviewThreadImage = [UIImageView new];
            [center addSubview:imageviewThreadImage];
            imageviewThreadImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            imageviewThreadImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(207.0/255.0) green:(215.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            [imageviewThreadImage sizeToFit];

            labelMessage = [UILabel new];
            [center addSubview:labelMessage];
            labelMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelMessage sizeToFit];
            [labelMessage setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = screenWidth - 10 - 36;
            labelMessage.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            labelMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
            labelMessage.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            //labelMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(207.0/255.0) green:(215.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            //labelMessage.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            bottom = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:bottom];
            bottom.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [bottom sizeToFit];

            labelCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCat];
            labelCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCat sizeToFit];
            [labelCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            labelCat.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            labelCat.numberOfLines = 0;

            labelSubCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelSubCat];
            labelSubCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelSubCat sizeToFit];
            [labelSubCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelSubCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelCountry = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCountry];
            labelCountry.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCountry sizeToFit];
            [labelCountry setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelCountry.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];


            youtube = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:youtube];
            youtube.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [youtube sizeToFit];
            }

            return self;
        }

        - (void)layoutSubviews
        {
            [super layoutSubviews];
            // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
            // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
            [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

            // Set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the mutli-line bodyLabel based on the evaluated width of the label's frame,
            // as this will allow the text to wrap correctly, and as a result allow the label to take on the correct height.
            self.labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.labelMessage.frame);
        }

        - (void)updateConstraints {
            [super updateConstraints];

            if (self.didSetupConstraints) return;

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary7 = @{@"main":main};
            NSArray *constraint_H37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[main]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary7];

            NSArray *constraint_V37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[main]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary7];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H37];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_V37];

            //NSString *text = labelMessage.text;

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary3 = @{@"top":top,@"center":center,@"bottom":bottom,@"youtube":youtube};
            NSArray *constraint_H3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[top]-5-[center(>=50)]-5-[bottom]-5-[youtube(>=0)]-10-|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H33cvcv4545 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[youtube]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H33 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[top]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H333 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[center]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H3335657 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottom]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary4 = @{@"labelUser":labelUser,@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelUser]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary45 = @{@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4555 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelDate]|"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewsDictionary45];

            NSArray *constraint_H44 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelUser]-20-[labelDate]-5-|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary48 = @{@"labelMessage":labelMessage,@"imageviewThreadImage":imageviewThreadImage};



            NSArray *constraint_H48 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelMessage]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary48];

            NSArray *constraint_H48342 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary48];



            NSArray *constraint_H448345fgdfg = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary48];

            CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
            //CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;


            NSArray *constraint_H448345fgdfgdfdf454 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-46-[labelMessage(%f)]-10-|",screenWidth - 51]
                                                   options:0
                                                   metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary48];




            /**NSArray *constraint_H448 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelMessage]-5-|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
             views:viewsDictionary48];**/

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary488 = @{@"labelCat":labelCat,@"labelCountry":labelCountry,@"labelSubCat":labelSubCat};
            NSArray *constraint_H488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCat]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCountry]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898fgf54 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelSubCat]|"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary488];

            NSArray *constraint_H4488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelCat]-10-[labelSubCat]-10-[labelCountry]"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewsDictionary488];



            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H3];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H33];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H333];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H44];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48];
            //[self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4555];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H3335657];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H488];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48342];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4488];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448345fgdfg];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48898];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48898fgf54];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448345fgdfgdfdf454];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H33cvcv4545];



            self.didSetupConstraints = YES;

        }


        -(void)setYoutube: (NSString*)youtubeID :(NSString*)title {

            if(youtubeID.length > 0){

            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



                webviewYoutube = [UIWebView new];
                [youtube addSubview:webviewYoutube];
                webviewYoutube.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
                [webviewYoutube sizeToFit];

                [webviewYoutube setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
                [webviewYoutube setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];


                NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html>\
                           <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                           <script type='text/javascript'>\
                           </script>\
                           <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1' frameborder='0'>\
                           </body>\
                           </html>", 100, 80, youtubeID];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
                [webviewYoutube loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];


                NSDictionary *viewsDictionary7 = @{@"webviewYoutube":webviewYoutube};
                NSArray *constraint_H37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[webviewYoutube(80)]|"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary7];

                NSArray *constraint_V37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[webviewYoutube(100)]"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary7];
                [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H37];
                [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_V37];

                CGRect newFrame = youtube.frame;

                newFrame.size.height = 100;
                [youtube setFrame:newFrame];


            });

            }else{

            }
        }





        - (void)awakeFromNib {
            // Initialization code
        }

        - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
            [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        @end
```

The UITableView cellForRowIndexPAth:

```
if(tableView == tableViewPost){
            //static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

            //PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem2";

            PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            //cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
            //cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            }

            Post *t = (Post*)[tmpArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.labelMessage.text = t.message;
            cell.labelCat.text = t.cat;
            cell.labelSubCat.text = t.subcat;
            cell.labelCountry.text = t.country;
            cell.labelUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", t.user];
            cell.labelDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", t.date];
            [cell setYoutube:t.youtube :@""];

            [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
            [cell.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
            return cell;
            }
```

The UITableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
            if(tableView == tableViewPost){

            int h = 0;
            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem2";
            PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            //PostTableViewCell *cell = (PostTableViewCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


            }

            [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
            [cell.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];


            CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
            //CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];



            return height + h;
            }
```

The Model Object that stored the Post Data:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

        @interface Post : NSObject


        @property int idThread;
        @property int postID;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *user;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *message;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *youtube;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *desc;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *cat;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *subcat;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *country;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *date;
        @property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *imageName;
        @end



        #import "Post.h"

        @implementation Post

        @enda
```

Comment: Should i create another PostTableViewCell called PostTableViewYoutubeCell and check if youtube value exists if not then render PostTableViewCell or else render PostTableViewYoutubeCell?